# seeing if server allows use of ftp_exec for cli commands

Tags: php, conditional-statements, ftp-client

So I've been doing some conditional test, and yet I am getting errors. Basically what I am trying to do is see if using CLI with `ftp_` functions will work on a server.

My test:

```
if(ftp_exec($connect,'ls -l'))
   $canuse = true;
else
   $canuse = false;
```

But this does not work on my server as it is blocked. Is there a test I can do without getting these errors and ruining my JSON (this trial returns a block of json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either turn off all of the error_reporting/display_error options, so the warnings/errors are suppressed, or you could try the OB system to catch the junk:

```
... build some json
ob_start();
... do ftp tests
$junk = ob_end_clean();
... build more json
```

All of the ftp errors would get caught in the ob buffer, and then thrown away when you shut down the buffer at the conclusion of the ftp test.